# Multiple form submission occurring as I submit form using window.jkey() end key

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am having an issue which has become headache for me. I am using this function to submit a form using codeigniter to complete a sales transaction. For this purpose I am using jquery keys plugin to submit the form as "end" key is pressed. Here is its code:

```
$(window).jkey('end',function(){
    $('#complete_sale_form').submit();
});
```

please someone help me to get rid of problem if someone accidently holds down END key on keyboard or presses it for multiple times in a second multiple times sales gets inserted in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with "jkey", but something like the following might work for you :)

```
var pressed = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 35){ //end key
      if(pressed === false){
          $('#complete_sale_form').submit();
          pressed = true;
          }
      }
   });
```

This website provides an interactive way to get the keyCodes that you're looking for: https://www.west-wind.com/WestwindWebToolkit/samples/Ajax/Html5AndCss3/KeyCodeChecker.aspx

Comment: Thanks entiendoNull you saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to check if the form has been previously submitted.

```
var formSubmitted = false;
$(window).jkey('end',function(){
 if(formSubmitted) return;
  formSubmitted = true;
  $('#complete_sale_form').submit(); 
});
```